# "Failed to compile" React Aseets Folder in wrong place

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Error Received.

> ./src/views/DomeCalculator.jsx Module not found: Can't resolve
>   'assets/img/calc/both.png' in 'C:\apps\open-dome-app\src\views'

These images are located in `open-dome-app/src/aseets/`

I am having trouble getting `webpack` to reference image assets in my `assets` folder.
How can one change from absolute paths?

Comment: Have you added resolve aliases in your webpack config? That way you could access assets like e.g. `src/assets/`, also, check your spelling.

Comment: how are you insering those images to the dom? I.e: how are you importing them?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, one way to solve this would be to add resolve aliases in webpack config.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const webpackConfig = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
  },
  ...
}
```